# Почему размер структуры не совпадает с размером суммы ее элементов?

Tags: c

с помощью функции sizeof пытаюсь определить размер данной структуры:

```
struct BitMapFileHeader
{
    WORD bfType; // Тип файла (должен быть BM).
    DWORD bfSize; // Размер файла в байтах.
    WORD bfReserved1; 
    WORD bfReserved2; // Зарезервированные поля.
    DWORD bfOffBits; // Смещение битового массива относительно начала файла.
} BMF;
```

Получаю значение = 16, почему так? DWORD же, по идее, занимает 4 байта, а WORD - 2.

Comment: это происходит из-за выравнивания полей структуры, на хабре на эту тему есть хорошая [статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/142662/)

Comment: Где Вы взяли такой размер? Проверил - BitMapFileHeader занимает 14 байт, в файлах bmp поле bfOffBits лежит на 10-м байте. `76...` здесь: `0000000000: 42 4D F6 00 00 00 00 00 │ 00 00 76 00 00 00 28 00`

Comment: @MBo, не понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: @Gleb Kamisaraw Если вы прочитаете заголовок битмапа в структуру, объявленную каким-то левым образом, то там будет фигня. Я привёл первую строчку 16-ричного дампа от bmp-файла, можно увидеть, что размер 14 байт, то же самое у меня выдаёт sizeof для данной структуры

Comment: @MBo, так ведь у меня тоже должно быть 14 байт

Comment: @Gleb Kamisaraw `Получаю значение = 16` ?  Это может означать использование неверного объявления структуры

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в так называемом *выравнивании*. Память устроена так, что быстрее всего четырёхбайтовые значения загружаются в регистры, если адрес их первого байта делится на 4.

Похожая история с двухбайтовыми значениями, которые должны быть *выравнены* на границу 2 байта.

Компилятор выравнивает значения в структурах за вас. Предположу (это надо проверить) что 2 «лишних» байта появились после `bfType`, перед `bfSize`.

Лишние байты никак не используются, просто ускоряют программу.

Для того, чтобы отключить выравнивание применяют директиву компилятора `pragma pack` либо директиву `__declspec(align)`:

```
__declspen(align(1)) struct BitMapFileHeader
{
    WORD bfType; // Тип файла (должен быть BM).
    DWORD bfSize; // Размер файла в байтах.
    WORD bfReserved1; 
    WORD bfReserved2; // Зарезервированные поля.
    DWORD bfOffBits; // Смещение битового массива относительно начала файла.
} BMF;
```

`align(1)` означает выравнивание на границу байта, все значения в структуре будут расположены вплотную друг к другу.

[Подробности](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/align-cpp?view=msvc-160)

Comment: В данном случае изменять упаковку нельзя, всё-таки это стандарт на формат bmp, но она на самом деле уже align(1), автор ошибается с размером.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma pack( push, 1)
```

Потом структуры с упаковкой. Чтоб вернуться к оптимизированным выравниваниям.

```
#pragma pack( pop)
```